# AVERAGE not calculated proper in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have written the following expression,

```
#for the 1st Column
CASE WHEN month = 'Nov' 
THEN AVG(Marks by Student) 
END

#for the 2nd Column
CASE WHEN month = 'Dec' 
THEN AVG(Marks by Student) 
END
```

I have Month as prompt. So, when I run the report. The data is being displayed only for December. But when I select November in prompt, November data is displayed.

Is there anything am going wrong with the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Wait you are saying that the result is "wrong" because it displays November when you FILTER for November?!

You do know that filters are actually WHERE clauses which cut off the data stream!